# how to access records in csv helper

Tags: c#, csv, helper

The code below reads a column of a csv file.
It does that properly.
I want to copy var records to a decimal array.
I am using csv helper.
How best to do it?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = new List<Filevalues>();
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = new Filevalues
        {            
            File_vals = csv.GetField<decimal>("File_vals"),   
        };

        records.Add(record);
    }
}

public class Filevalues
{
    public decimal File_vals{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't think csvreader knows the length of the csv file in advance to initialize the array properly eg. var decs = new decimal[123]; you could start with an array of size x and resize it accordingly but I would suggest to stick with the list and use .ToArray() at the end to get an array out of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its most simple:

```
using var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filename), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
csv.GetRecords<Filevalues>().Select(f => f.File_vals).ToArray();
```

(I think I'd ToList() it instead of array, and work with the List)

If the CSV is so simple that it's just a list of decimals, I might skip using a CSV library all together:

```
File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1).Select(decimal.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Actually there are other columns too. Not a simple csv. List is ok for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var listOfDecimals = new List<decimal>();
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        listOfDecimals.Add(csv.GetField<decimal>("File_vals"));
    }

    var arrayOfDecimals = listOfDecimals.ToArray();
}
```

ToArray: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray

Or:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = new List<Filevalues>();
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = new Filevalues
        {
            File_vals = csv.GetField<decimal>("File_vals"),   
        };
        records.Add(record);
    }

    var arrayOfDecimals = records.Select(x => x.File_vals).ToArray();
}

public class Filevalues
{
    public decimal File_vals{ get; set; }
}
```

LINQ Projection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations

Comment: Actually my problem is -   conversion of var to decimal. Just need to copy to a public decimal array. Thanks.

Comment: @AAH - `conversion of var to decimal` this statement is invalid, since `var` isn't a type. It is a simple keyword that can be used to implictly defined the type instead of explicitly naming the type eg. `var foo = new Foo();` instead of `Foo foo = new Foo();`, so you wanted to have `conversion of Filevalues to decimal` - since `var record` is actually the type `Filevalues record` - which the LINQ projection solution is showing.

Comment: @AAH - `var` -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var